# Yup Validation - How to make field required if property.length > than 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, validation, yup

Given a form with a countries and provinces list I have the follow rule:

1. Country field/select is **required**
2. Some countries have provinces. When the user select a country, the API will fetch a list of provinces.
3. If there is provinces for this country, the Field/Select provinces is **required**.
4. If there is no provinces for this country after the API fetch, the Field/Select provinces is not required.

My code is being writing using React Hooks...

```
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    country: yup
      .object()
      .required(t("common.validation.field_required"))
      .nullable(),
    province: yup.object().when() // How to validate provinces to be required?
});


const [provinces, setProvinces] = useState<Province>([]);

const fetchProvinces = (country: Country) => {
 // Code for API fetch ...
 setProvinces(apiResult);
}

...
return (
 ...
 <Autocomplete id="countries-list" options={countriesList} onChange={fetchProvinces} ... />
 <Autocomplete id="provinces-list" options={provincesList} ... />
 ...
);
```

How to make `provinces-list` field only required (using YUP) if `provinces` property have some content (`provinces.length > 0`)?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found was to create a fake property called `hasProvinces` when setting the form properties. When we select a country that has provinces, we set `hasProvinces` as `true`. Now, using **yup**, I can set the "when" clause. Follow a sample:

```
interface MyForm {
   country: Country;
   hasProvinces: boolean;
   province: Province;
}
...



const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    country: yup
      .object()
      .required(t("common.validation.field_required"))
      .nullable(),
    hasProvinces: yup.boolean(),
    province: yup.object().when("hasProvinces", {
      is: true,
      then: yup
        .object()
        .required(t("common.validation.field_required"))
        .nullable(),
      otherwise: yup.object().notRequired().nullable(),
    })
});

const [countries, countriesList] = useState<Country[]>([]);
const [provinces, setProvinces] = useState<Province[]>([]);

const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState<MyForm>(initialFormValues);

const fetchProvinces = (country: Country) => {
 const provinces = ... // Code for API fetch

 if(provinces.length > 0){
    setFormValues({...formValues, hasProvinces: true});
    setProvinces(provinces);
 }else{
    setFormValues({...formValues, hasProvinces: false});
    setProvinces([]);
 }
}

...
return (
 ...
 <Autocomplete id="country" options={countriesList} onChange={fetchProvinces} ... />
 <Autocomplete id="province" options={provincesList} ... />
 ...
);
```